# Does もあれば have set phrases?

Tags: set-phrases

I came across a sentence using もあれば where there wasn't a conditional. あれば got translated as sometimes:

> 名詞から動詞が派生していること**もあれば**、その逆のこと**もある**。
>   Sometimes a verb is derived from a noun and sometimes it is the other way around.

Looking for more examples, I saw some more sentences with this "sometimes this, sometimes that" pattern. I basically understand how to construct a sentence with this pattern, but I also found some where I couldn't' tell what もあれば was doing:

> 京都から高野山までは、3時間もあれば行ける距離です。
>   Kyoto is about 3 hours distance from Mt. Koya
>   10分もあれば支度できます。
>   It only takes me 10 minutes to get ready

What is もあれば's function in the last two examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ば` is conditional just as in the first example. `も` in these cases means something like 'as less as'. The literal translations are respectively (Don't expect that they are grammatical or natural in English):

> (The distance) from Kyoto to Koyasan
>   is such that, if you have as less as
>   three hours, you can get there.
>
> If I have as less as ten minutes, I can get ready.

By the way, although I know that it is not only the responsibility of the English speaking people, I feel it unnatural when people write something like `Mt. Koyasan`. It is as strange as saying `Mt. Mont Blanc`, `salsa sauce`, `Volkswagen car`, etc.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I see now that all of the examples have a conditional. I was relying too heavily on the translations.

Comment: Or "chai tea".  Damn that pisses me off when I hear it.