# Can someone help with this sentence? Or - how to decipher the structure in general

Tags: translation, grammar

Could someone help me with understanding/translating this sentence?

あっちがメディア化ともなれば必然的に打ち合わせ等の優先順位はこっちが後回しになります。

The sentence before: マンガ編集者というのは他人も担当作家を抱えています。 (which I read as something like: Being a manga editor means being responsible for several authors...) The sentence after that: 自分の作品の価値を上げ担当編集者に振り向いてもらうことだけ。 (which I read as something like: So the only thing left for me to do is raising the value of my work and thus turn/hand it over to the editor in charge...) Thanks!

It's sometimes so frustrating - even if you know or at least can look up all the words in questions, I sometimes stumble upon sentences where I just never can figure out the whole meaning behind it. Any advice for these kind of encounters? Or is it just a lack of more in-depth and more fundamental grammar principles? In this particular sentence, the あっち and こっち really kills me. Appreciate any help! And stay safe y'all!

Comment: The context of the sentence would be helpful in properly translating the あっち and こっち. Can you include the sentences before and after?

Comment: Sure! Sorry, for missing out on that.
So the context is print and publishing company.
 
The sentence before:
マンガ編集者というのは他人も担当作家を抱えています。
(which I read as something like: Being a manga editor means being responsible for several authors...)

The sentence after that:
自分の作品の価値を上げ担当編集者に振り向いてもらうことだけ。
(which I read as something like: So the only thing left for me to do is raising the value of my work and thus turn/hand it over to the editor in charge...)

Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to include the context you posted above in your comment, to make it more conspicuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- あっち is "their/that side", and in this context it refers to another manga an editor is assigned to. こっち is "our/this side" or "my manga". We can notice this because the previous sentence is about an editor having many mangaka to work with.
- ～ともなれば is a variant of [～となれば](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/108/5010) ("once/if it has been decided that ～"). This も used with a conditional expression roughly means "only" or "just". See: [Does もあれば have set phrases?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1779/5010)
- ～を後回しにする is a common set phrase that means "to put [something] on the back-burner". ～が後回しになる means "to be put on the back-burner".

> あっちがメディア化ともなれば
> Once another manga is set to be made into anime, ...
> Just by the fact that another manga will be made into anime, ...
>
> 必然的に
> inevitably, ... / naturally, ...
>
> 打ち合わせ等の優先順位は
> as for the priorities of meetings and such,
>
> こっちが後回しになります
> our side will be put on the back-burner.

<sub>*メディア化 ("media-ization") usually means アニメ化, but sometimes ドラマCD化.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! This helped a lot!